# All caps in the user profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

The user profiles ( https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10042/michaelt ) are in all caps.  Cutting and pasting from mine gives "MICHAELT".

[image: Snippit of my profile]

Could this be changed to the [small caps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) format so that if a name is copied and pasted it would instead come back as 'MichaelT'?

I came across this while grabbing a name to @ping someone in chat (which I don't know if it is case sensitive or not, but wasn't going to paste all caps either way - thats yelling their name).

Comment: You know you just wanted to yell at me. YOU KNOW IT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this, made the user name on profile page to have regular case. The change will go out after the next production build.

Comment: Verified the change.  Thank you (though if you ever want to consider a small cap font, it would likely fit well too).